# How do I mould a specific portion of a head model to match the shape of the one beneath it?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, sculpting, unreal-engine

[image]

This is my first time using Blender, for the purpose of fixing an edited head model in the video game Fallen Order. My goal is very simple, I just want to alter the edited head model on top, so that the back of the neck matches the one highlighted in orange beneath it. However, my every attempt to either manipulate the vertices directly, use sculpt tools, or use the shrinkwrap function just results in a deformed mesh that has bumps or tears or weird distortions, and I'm really clueless as to what to do. I just want to edit the neck so it no longer clips with the clothing of the character it belongs to, but its so outside my capabilites I really need help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic bullet to this kind of thing. Modifying existing models takes time and skill. But here are some tips.

To mimic some other model's shape, you can set the source model to wireframe mode and then select your new model. Enter edit mode, activate Proportional Editing and push and pull your shape based on source mesh shape. This usually works best for rough shape changes like changing proportions, matching pose of another model, or modify side or front profile of your model etc.

[image]

To drop specific vertices on the surface of your source model, you can enable face snapping, then select some vertices in your new mesh, and move a vert. This makes the vertex snap to the target surface. This is precision work, don't expect to select a big clump of vertices and then expect something good to happen if you move them. Start slowly and see how snapping works.

[image]

Sculpting tools too can be very useful. Do changes is small steps. Grab and Elastic deform brushes are my favourites. Here you can also use the wireframe trick, simply set your source model viewport display mode to wireframe, and the shape your new mesh in Solid shading mode.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I really appreciate it! I'm finding it incredibly difficult to edit via vertices as there are thousands on this mesh, and as the shape of the neck is wafer thin, the tiniest movement causes a deformation. Do you have any advice for the sculpt tools? I found myself accidentally tearing holes in the mesh using grab, and it was very hard to retain a smooth mesh shape as required on a neck. 

I will give snapping a go too, I'm not after a perfect result, just one that will reshape it so I have no neck clipping ingame.

Comment: Proportional editing (also called soft selection in some software) helps with issue of too many vertices to move, you drag one or more, and nearby vertices will follow. You can also adjust the falloff size for this effect with your mouse wheel. Without seeing the model it is hard to say what is causing holes, maybe your mesh surface has seams? Sculpting tools are usually the best option for medium and high resolution organic mesh shaping (in any 3d software). Grab brush for example has very soft effect,  and you can smooth the result afterwards by shift + left clicking mesh.